# PHP Russian symbols become question marks

Tags: javascript, php, string

I have a problem of Russian characters becoming question marks somewhere here:

1. I send an array of words (strings) to PHP handler (using Ajax)

[image]

2. In my php handler, I change this words and join them in one string

[image]

3. Then I use echo to send this string back as a response in my JS script

[image]

4. I alert this string and see question marks (in the example below the right response should be %п%%п%)

[image]

How can I fix it?

I tried:

1. Adding AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 in .htaccess
2. Adding meta charset="UTF-8" to my html file
3. Encoding all my files using UTF-8

Comment: transform.....to what? What should be the result of the transformation?

Comment: I add percent mark before first letter and after the last one

Comment: what's the encoding of the site and the PHP-script?

Comment: The encoding of all files is UTF-8

Comment: the best approach might be to use `json_encode` to encode the string

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works. But still it is really strange. Why it isn't working without json_encode

Comment: @CMTV, maybe, your's ajax doesn't really gives utf-8 to php script. Try `return mb_convert_encoding($out, 'utf-8', 'cp1251')` in yours `.php` and watch output